# Synaptic touchpad disabled after boot

Tags: touchpad, synaptic

Every time I restart Ubuntu the touch pad is set to disabled. I have to manually trigger it via the keyboard short cut (FN + F7).  How can I set it so it is automatically enabled?

Comment: Was this happening after you log in or before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually "enable touchpad", you can add the command in startup application.

```
xinput list
```

[image]

You can access any element by its ID.

Enable Touch pad device by setting to "1"

```
xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 1
```

You can add this command in startup applications
[image]
This is not a recommended solution, if you find any better solutions prefer them.

Comment: No luck. even tried xinput enable 12 in start up program.

Comment: I added the screenshot of xinput , you can access touchpad by its id. Here I have my id = 12, so,I used "set-prop 12". replace it with your id

Answer (score 0):

system settings --> mouse&touchpad.
click enable touchpad.

Comment: looking for a more automatic solution.