# Elantech touchpad disabled on boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, touchpad, elantech

My touchpad of my acer AO725 is always disabled on boot. I have already tried a couple of methods that worked for other people, like [Touchpad disabled at boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660393/touchpad-disabled-at-boot) and [Synaptic touchpad disabled after boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397129/synaptic-touchpad-disabled-after-boot), but none of them worked.

> Run acpi_listen and hit the fn+F7 keystroke; the output should be
>   similiar to this one: `hotkey ATKD NNNNNNNN 00000000` Where `NNNNNNNN` is
>   the fn+F7 keystroke's ACPI code;

My output of that command is `PNP0C14:00 000000bc 00000000`, and if I use 000000bc in the next steps, it does not generate the file it should generate. I have also noticed that some of the other key combinations (`fn + f5-7` to be precise) have the exact same output

---

excerpt from xinput list:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Weird thing is, I can enable touchpad via `xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 1`, but it does not work when I put that in the startup applications.

Running Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

After doing `sudo apt autoremove` I had the same issue with Elantech Touchpad.

Adding the following line `blacklist ideapad_laptop` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and rebooting (could also reload the config) the laptop fixed the issue for me.

> Lenovo Y700
>   Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: Maybe `ideapad_laptop`? There is no `ideapad_lenovo` module.

Comment: @Pilot6 yep, changed typo.